# acpid - Hibernate When Unplugged

Tags: acpi, lubuntu, acpid

I'm new to programming for Linux (lubuntu specifically) and I'm working on a project to get an old, discarded laptop up and running the way I want it. I have acpi and acpid installed, and when I run the acpi command, I]m informed of whether my laptop is plugged in (charging) or unplugged (discharging).

I would now like to have the laptop automatically hibernate when the laptop is discharging. My first thought was to write a script that would poll acpi every 30 seconds or so and then run a hibernate command whenever it responded with the word "discharging". However, I understand that acpid is the better tool to use, as it is more event-driven. I can't seem to find any material on making a laptop hibernate when unplugged - any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The `acpid` daemon should receive battery events by ACPI subsystem. When you unplug/plug the laptop there should be related battery events. The events can be associated with actions like power off/suspend/hibernate the system and so on.

Firstly, try to verify it by watching `/var/log/messages` or related log files when you unplug the laptop. There should be something like

```
... ACPI action undefined: ...
```

If there is nothing you can try `acpi_listen` command which connects to acpid and listens for events.

Then, you can configure a generic event handler under the `/etc/acpi/events` directory for battery events. Create there a file e.g. `battery.conf` with the following content:

```
event=battery.*
action=/etc/acpi/actions/battery.sh
```

It says that any battery event should be processed by the script `battery.sh`. In this script, I would monitor the battery status available from the `/proc/acpi/battery/*/state` file. Especially, check the line **"charging state"** which should change to **"discharging"** when you unplug the laptop or **"charging/charged"** when you plug it back.

Based on this information, you can run the hibernate command from the event handler `battery.sh`. Furthermore, you can find some other useful examples e.g. on [github](https://github.com/rickwangtw/acpid/tree/master/samples).

Comment: I can confirm that acpid is running, but I don't think it's creating an event when I unplug the laptop. I set up the battery.conf and battery.sh files, and in battery.sh I just make a popup using xmessage. Running the .sh file manually works, but it is not executed when I unplug my laptop. Also, running `acpi_listen` doesn't show me anything when I unplug the laptop. The only difference I see is that if I run acpi, it says "charging" when plugged in, but "discharging" when I unplug. Any advice?

Comment: Are there any files under /proc/acpi/battery/ ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. no, the only things in /proc/acpi are button (directory), event (file), and wakeup (file)